# For this integral: $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x \tan(x) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

For the following integral: $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x \tan(x) dx=\frac{G}{2}-\frac{\pi\ln(2)}{8}$$ where $G$ is Catalan's constant. After integrating by parts, it is equivalent to compute $\int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\cos(x)) dx$. How can I proceed further?

Comment: There is an infinite series representation for $\log(\cos(x))$ in this post, does that give you enough to solve the problem? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292326/log-sine-and-log-cos-integral-with-fun-result

Comment: @Joe That can also be used to evaluate this integral.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We want to evaluate the definite integral
$$ \mathcal{I} = \displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln( \cos x ) \ \mathrm dx $$

We note that
$$ \begin{align} \ln(\cos{x}) &=\frac12\Big( ( \ln(\sin{x}) + \ln(\cos{x}) ) -(\ln(\sin{x}) -\ln(\cos{x}))\Big) \\ &= \frac12 \ln \Big( \frac{\sin(2x)}{2}\Big) -\frac12\ln(\tan{x}) \\ &= \frac12\ln(\sin(2x)) -\frac12 \ln(2) - \frac12\ln(\tan{x}) \end{align}$$

Using this, the integrand simplifies to

$$ \mathcal{I} =\frac12 \displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(\sin(2x))\ \mathrm dx - \frac12 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(\tan{x})\ \mathrm dx  -\frac12\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln{2} \ \mathrm dx $$

Starting with the second integral, it is a well known result.

$$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(\tan{x})\ \mathrm dx = -G$$

$ G$ denotes Catalan's constant.

For the first integral, the substitution $ 2x=t $ gives
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\sin{x})\ \mathrm dx $$
This integral just equals $ - \dfrac{\pi}{4}\ln{2}$, by using the well known result

$$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\sin{x})\ \mathrm dx = - \dfrac{\pi}{2}\ln{2}$$

The third integral is trivial and equals $ \frac{\pi}{4}\ln{2}$.

Summing up the values of the 3 integrals, our original integral equals

$$ \boxed{\boxed{\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\ln(\cos x )\,\mathrm dx =\frac G2 - \dfrac{\pi}{4}\ln{2}}} $$

And using integration by parts,

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\frac\pi4}x\tan x\,\mathrm dx &= \frac\pi8\ln2+\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\ln(\cos x)\,\mathrm dx \\ &= \frac G2-\frac\pi8\ln2\end{align}$$
Which matches the result given in the OP.

**EDIT**

As people had problems with the second integral, here is solution.

The Catalan's constant is defined as

$$G=\beta(2)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}$$

Here $\beta(\cdot)$ denotes the Dirichlet's beta function.

In our integral, we substitute $\tan x = t$.

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\ln \tan x\,\mathrm dx &= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \int_0^1 x^{2k}\ln x\,\mathrm dx \\ &= -\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}\\ &= -G\end{align}$$

Comment: This is a nice answer. Do you have a reference for the `well known' log sin and log tan integrals?

Comment: @Joe The log tan integral is provided in the "Integral representations" section of the Wikipedia page of Catalan's constant. The log sin integral is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2931388/931957).

Comment: @Joe Thank you! But how to achieve that series expansion formula?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Thank you. My question is how to get that G, actually I got these steps, and convert from that log(tan) to log(cos), then I stuck at log(cos) ....

Comment: @Laxmi Narayan Bhandari thank you, I like the derivation of the log sin integral.  Unfortunately that Wikipedia page on G only lists the log tan integral, and doesn't derive it

Comment: @MathFail, great question! I don't know how to derive the series expansion formula in the question that I linked. In that question they claim it to be a 'classical result', so presumably it can be found online. I did a couple of searches but I couldn't find it, maybe you could post it as a separate question?

Comment: @Joe Yes, I also search that series formula on Google but couldn't find it, but it looks at a Fourier series?

Comment: @MathFail If you want, I can write another answer using the series expansion. I will be providing a derivation of the series too. It is a Fourier series.

Comment: @Joe Check out the edit. I have provided a derivation for the log tan integral.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Yes, could you show the series solution? Thank you!

Comment: @MathFail Ok, I will post it later. A little bit busy right now.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Thank you! Take your time~

Comment: @MathFail I have posted the solution. If you are satisfied with any of the two solutions, then please consider accepting the answer you like.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari thank you! and for your power series expansion on ln(1+z) ,here z=e^2ix , I remember the series converges for |z|<1 right? but |e^2ix|=1 .

Comment: @MathFail The method isn't rigourous but it works. But I have seen many people use this method. Maybe some high level theorem I don't know about can verify the convergence of the sum.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Thank you! I have accepted your answer, the integral method, I thought this method is more rigorous than the series method you posted. Sorry for the delay, I was busy these two days and not went to this site, thank you very much!!!

Comment: @MathFail No problem. :D

Answer (score 5):

Using the complex definition of cosine,

$$\begin{align}\ln\cos x&= \ln\Big(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2\Big) \\ &= ix+\ln(1+e^{-2ix})-\ln2 \\ &= -ix+\ln(1+e^{2ix})-\ln2 \\ \implies \ln\cos x &= -\ln 2 +\frac12(\ln(1+e^{2ix})+\ln(1+e^{-2ix})) \\ &= -\ln 2 -\frac12 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac1k(e^{2ikx}+e^{-2ikx}) \\ \ln\cos x&= -\ln2-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}k\cos(2kx) \end{align}$$

This is the Fourier series of $\ln\cos x$. Using this result,

$$\begin{align}I =\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln\cos x\,\mathrm dx &= \int_0^{\pi/4}-\ln2 -\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}k \cos(2k x)\,\mathrm dx \\ &= -\frac\pi4\ln2-\sum_{k=1} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}k\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos(2kx)\,\mathrm dx \\  &= -\frac\pi4\ln2-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k^2} \sin\Big(\frac{k\pi}2\Big) \end{align}$$

Now, we note that for $k\in\mathbb Z$

$$\sin(k\pi) =0 , \quad \sin\Big(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}2\Big) = (-1)^k $$

Using this, we re-index our sum.

$$\begin{align}I &= -\frac\pi4\ln2-\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{2k+1}(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2} \\ &= -\frac\pi4\ln2+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2} \\ I &= \frac G2-\frac\pi4\ln2 \end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

To the nice solutions - just to add another approach (which does not use the trigonometry):
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/4}x\tan xdx=(x=\tan^{-1}t)\,\,\int_0^1\tan^{-1}t\frac{tdt}{1+t^2}$$
$$= (IBP)\,\,\,\,\frac{\pi\ln2}{8}\ln2-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t^2)}{1+t^2}dt$$
Making change $x=1/t$
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t^2)}{1+t^2}dt=\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx-2\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t^2)}{1+t^2}dt=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx-2G$$
The last integral it is easy to evaluate via complex integration:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln(1-ix)}{1+x^2}dx$$
Closing the contour in the upper half-plane (where we have one simple pole and no branch points for the chosen integrand)
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln(1-ix)}{1+x^2}dx=2\pi i\operatorname{Res}_{x=i}\frac{\ln(1-ix)}{1+x^2}=2\pi i\frac{\ln2}{2i}=\pi\ln2$$
Taking all together
$$I=\frac{\pi\ln2}{8}-\frac{\pi\ln2}{4}+\frac{G}{2}=\frac{G}{2}-\frac{\pi\ln2}{8}$$

Answer (score 1):

By integration by parts, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x \tan x d x &=-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x d(\ln (\cos x)) \\
&=-\left[ x \ln (\cos x)\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (\cos x) d x\\&= -\frac{\pi}{4} \ln \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (\cos x) d x
\end{aligned}
$$

By my [post](https://artisticmathematics.quora.com/https-www-quora-com-How-do-we-find-the-integral-displaystyle-int_-0-frac-pi-4-ln-cos-x-d-x-tag-answer-Lai-Johnny?ch=17&oid=57830827&share=d6e959a0&srid=CCOmo&target_type=post) in Quora,

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (\cos x) dx =-\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+\frac{G}{2},\tag*{} $$
$\textrm{where G is the Catalan's constant.}$

Hence we can conclude that

$$\begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x \tan x d x &= -\frac{\pi}{4} \ln \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) -\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+\frac{G}{2}\\&=  -\frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2+\frac{G}{2}\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the integral as
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x \tan x d x 
&=-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x d[\ln (2\cos x)]
\overset{ibp}=
 -\frac{\pi}{8} \ln2 +I
\end{align}
where
$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (2\cos x) dx
$, along with $J=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (2\sin x) dx
$. Note
\begin{align}
I-J&=-\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\ln (\tan x )dx=G\\
I+J &= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (2\sin 2x) dx
\overset{x\to\frac\pi4 -x}= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (2\cos 2x) dx\\
&=\frac12 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (4\sin 2x\cos2x) dx \overset{2x\to x}= \frac14 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (2\sin 2x) dx\\
&= \frac12 (I+J)=0
\end{align}
which leads to $I=\frac12G$ and
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x \tan x d x =  \frac12G -\frac{\pi}{8} \ln2 $$

Comment: Nice substitutions. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Another way,
\begin{align}J&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}t\tan t dt\\
&\overset{x=\tan t}=\int_0^1 \frac{x\arctan x}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2}\left(\underbrace{\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+u^2}du}_{z=\frac{u}{x}}\right)dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)(1+x^2z^2)}dxdz\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{(1-z^2)(1+x^2z^2)}-\frac{1}{(1-z^2)(1+x^2)}\right)dxdz\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{z(1-z^2)}\left(\frac{z}{1+x^2z^2}-\frac{z}{1+x^2}\right)dxdz\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{z(1-z^2)}\left(\left(\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{z}{1+x^2z^2}dx}_{u=xz}\right)-z\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx\right)dz\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{z(1-z^2)}\left(\left(\int_0^z \frac{1}{1+u^2}du\right)-\frac{\pi z}{4}\right)dz\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\underbrace{\left[\left(\ln z-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-z^2)\right)\left(\left(\int_0^z \frac{1}{1+u^2}du\right)-\frac{\pi z}{4}\right)\right]_0^1}_{=0}-\\&\int_0^1 \left(\ln z-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-z^2)\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+z^2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)dz\\
&=-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln z}{1+z^2}dz+\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1 \ln z dz+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-z^2)}{1+z^2}dz-\frac{\pi}{8}\int_0^1
 \ln(1-z^2)dz\\
&=\text{G}-\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-z^2)}{1+z^2}dz-\frac{\pi}{8}\underbrace{\left[x\ln(1-x^2)-\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)-2x\right]_0^1}_{=2\ln 2-2}\\
&=\text{G}+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-z^2)}{1+z^2}dz}_{y=\frac{1-z}{1+z}}-\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2\\
&=\text{G}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{4y}{(1+y)^2}\right)}{1+y^2}dy-\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2\\
&=\text{G}+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln 2}{1+y^2}dy+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln y}{1+y^2}dy-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}dy-\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\text{G}-\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}dy}_{=\text{K}}\\
\text{K}&\overset{z=\frac{1-y}{1+y}}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+z}\right)}{1+z^2}dz=\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2-\text{K}\\
\text{K}&=\frac{1}{8}\pi\ln 2\\
J&=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}\text{G}-\frac{1}{8}\pi\ln 2}
\end{align}