# How do we prove that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x\cot xd x= \frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2+\frac{G}{2},$ where G is the Catalan’s constant?

Tags: integration, catalans-constant

After evaluating the integral in my [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4360569/732917),$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x \tan x d x =-\frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2+\frac{G}{2},
$$
then I want to know more about the value of its “partner” integral $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x \cot x d x.$$

First of all, I tried to make use of the integration by parts.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x \cot x d x &=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x d(\ln (\sin x)) \\
&=[x \ln (\sin x)]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (\sin x) d x \\
&=-\frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (\sin x) d x
\end{aligned}
$$

By the [post in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/917086/732917),
$$\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\ln(\sin x)\ dx=-\frac12\left(G+\frac\pi2\ln2\right),$$
I got a similar result for it.
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x \cot x d x=\frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2+\frac{G}{2}
$$

Do we have another method? Your contribution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h482639p2704267

Comment: Thank you for catching my typo, fixed.

Comment: You can use previous result. $\int_0^{\pi/4} x \cot x\, dx=\int_0^{\pi/4} x \tan x\, dx+\int_0^{\pi/4} x (\cot x - \tan x)\, dx$. Last integral transforms to $\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\pi/2} x \cot x\, dx$.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation is possible that avoids the calculation of an integral that results in another instance of Catalan's constant.  Recall the identity
$$\cot x - \tan x = 2 \cot 2x.$$  So let
$$\int_{x=0}^{\pi/4} x \cot x \, dx = I_1, \quad \int_{x=0}^{\pi/4} x \tan x \, dx = I_2,$$ from which we obtain
$$I_1 - I_2 = \int_{x=0}^{\pi/4} 2x \cot 2x \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{x=0}^{\pi/2} x \cot x \, dx. \tag{1}$$  Then we apply integration by parts as you had done with the choice $$u = x, \quad du = dx, \\ dv = \cot x \, dx, \quad v = \log \sin x$$ to obtain $$I_1 = I_2 + \frac{1}{2} \left(\left[ x \log \sin x \right]_{x=0}^{\pi/2} - \int_{x=0}^{\pi/2} \log \sin x \, dx \right) = I_2 - \frac{1}{2} \int_{x=0}^{\pi/2} \log \sin x \, dx. \tag{2}$$  Then [elementary arguments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690644/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-log-cosx-mathrmdx/) can be used to evaluate $$\int_{x=0}^{\pi/2} \log \sin x = -\frac{\pi}{2} \log 2, \tag{3}$$ which when combined with previous results, yields the desired answer.